# Por que as quebras de linhas entre elementos causam espaço entre eles?

Tags: html, quebras-de-linha, indentação

Estava realizando uma organização em alguns códigos aqui antes commitar e percebi que uma indentação no HTML causou um problema no meu layout, então fui inspecionar para descobri o que eu tinha feito de errado além de indentar, e descobri que as quebras de linhas para indentação acabaram aumentando o espaço entre 2 elementos.

Segue um exemplo que demonstra a mesma estrutura html indentada e inline (também [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/w7h9m3de/8/)):

```html
<div style="font-size: 44px;">
  <span>28.3</span>
  <span>km</span>
</div>

<div style="font-size: 44px;"><span>28.3</span><span>km</span></div>
```

## Perguntas:

- Por que isso ocorre?
- Como indentar meu código e não ter esse espaço?

Comment: ao meu ver faz sentido, porque entre as tags span, existe algum elemento (quebra de linha e espaço) apenas espaços antes ou depois da tag seriam desconsiderados

Comment: @h3nr1ke, só existe ali a quebra de linha e os recuos, mas se você remover todos os recuos, ele ainda manterá o espaço em banco, então é a quebra de linha que causa o espaço em branco. E poderia informar algum fonte sobre a afirmação: "apenas espaços antes ou depois da tag seriam desconsiderados"?

Comment: não tenho uma fonte... foi o teste que eu fiz no seu fiddle... mas as explicações do pessoal abaixo foram muito completas e cheias de referências ^^V

Answer (score 6):

Segundo o *W3*, todos os caracteres abaixo são considerados espaço em branco.

- ASCII space (`&#x0020;`)
- ASCII tab (`&#x0009;`)
- ASCII form feed (`&#x000C;`)
- Zero-width space (`&#x200B;`)

Uma quebra de linha é definida como `&#x000D;` ([*Carriage return*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return)) e `&#x000A;` (*[Line Feed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)*). E isso também a torna um espaço em branco.

A [ISO-8879](https://www.iso.org/standard/16387.html) especifica que uma quebra de linha imediatamente após uma marca de início deve ser ignorada, assim como uma quebra de linha imediatamente antes do fechamento de uma *tag*.

> **Nota 1:** Apesar de haver um espaço em branco + quebra de linha (que também é considerado espaço em branco), o navegador acaba condensando esses caracteres. É o mesmo que fazer `a    b` e a saída ser `a b`

> **Nota 2:** Vale lembrar que os navegadores interpretam dessa forma todos os elementos HTML, exceto `<pre>` e elementos com css `white-space: pre`.

---

<sup>Referências:

    ¹ https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/text.html#h-9.1 

    ² https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/text.html#line-breaks</sup>

Comment: `0x000D` eu tenho a impressão que não é o cara ter nulo. Pelo que me lembre, o caracter nulo é `0x0000`

Comment: Verdade @JeffersonQuesado. Corrigido.

Comment: Sobre o espaço de comprimento zero, como é algo que eu nunca havia visto, deixo essa referência para o leitor curioso: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space?wprov=sfti1

Answer (score 2):

Na realidade é justamente por conta da indentação que ocorre o espaçamento, pois se observar bem está sendo gerado um espaço, o motor de renderização de html dos navegadores ignora os espaços adicionais (quando há mais que 1 espaço), mas ainda assim o primeiro deles é renderizado, o ideal quando não se quer o espaço é que seja colocado na mesmo linha:

```
<div style="font-size: 44px;">
  <span>28.3</span><span>km</span>
</div>
```

Assim elimina-se o problema.

Comment: Não é por causa da indentação, é a quebra de linha mesmo. Se você deixar o segundo `span` no início da segunda linha, vai ter quebra de linha e neste caso não há espaços.

Comment: Na realidade o que você disse @LINQ, o problema é também a indentação, pois há espaços estão nela. Porém a quebra de linha também. Veja que o motor de renderização interpreta algum dos caracteres de quebra -\n ou \r- (não sei em qual SO ele está), mas renderiza como espaço também.
Neste fiddle tem um exemplo com todos os casos:https://jsfiddle.net/L287m1k4/

Comment: Pois bem, levando em conta a afirmação do @LINQ, que está correta, não é o espaço e sim a quebra de linha que está causando o espaço, e então como que ele renderiza um espaço se não há nenhum? Ou ele converte, qual a regra?

Comment: Na realidade a resposta do @Valdeir Psr está bem mas completa que a minha, é que alguns caracteres especiais também são renderizados como espaço em branco

Answer (score 1):

> Por que isso ocorre?

Essa diferença acontece porque, ao exibir o HTML, os *browsers* condensam uma sequência de caracteres em branco (i.e. espaços, quebras de linha etc) em apenas um espaço. Esse comportamento é padrão para qualquer elemento que não possuir a propriedade [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) definida como `pre` ou `pre-wrap`.

Aliás, é por isso, que, se você quiser exibir mais de um espaço, você não pode simplesmente usar os caracteres de espaço ( ) na marcação, já que, como vimos, estes são condensados. Nesse caso, pode-se usar várias entidades HTML `&nbsp;` (*non-breaking space*). Veja:

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
A&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;B <br />
|----|
```

> Como indentar meu código e não ter esse espaço?

Para remover os espaços entre os *spans*, você deve procurar algum jeito de remover (ou esconder) os caracteres em brancos que existem entre eles  no HTML (as quebras de linha e os espaços da indentação).

Uma forma de se fazer isso é simplesmente não os indentar, conforme feito no primeiro exemplo:

```html
<div>
  <span>1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span>
</div>
```

Uma outra alternativa é utilizar comentários, conforme mostra [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60173376/7445826) do SOen:

```html
<div>
     <span>1</span><!--
  --><span>2</span><!--
  --><span>3</span>
</div>
```

<sup>Note que agora todos os caracteres em branco (no exemplo, quebras de linha e espaços) fazem parte agora do comentário, e não da marcação que será exibida pelo *browser*.</sup>

Se você não puder mexer no HTML, uma outra opção, utilizando CSS, é reduzir o tamanho da fonte a zero para a `<div>` (que contém os espaços) e definir o tamanho normal para cada `<span>`. Algo assim:

```css
.without-spacing {
  font-size: 0;
}

.without-spacing span {
  font-size: initial;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
</div>

<div class="without-spacing">
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
</div>
```

<sup>Note que, neste último exemplo, não estamos removendo de fato os caracteres em branco, mas sim escondendo-os com esse pequeno artifício. Se você selecioná-los e "copiar", verá que ainda existirá um espaço entre cada elemento. Portanto, utilize essa alternativa apenas para fins visuais.</sup>

Comment: Àqueles que negativaram: por favor, queiram justificar. O comentário de _feedback_ é importante para que eu possa melhorar a resposta. Jamais ignoraria um comentário de _feedback_.