# Como funciona o espaçamento do elemento span?

Tags: html, css

Dependendo de como eu escrevo o código, o elemento span coloca um espaçamento.

```html
<div style="padding:20px; border:1px solid black; margin-bottom:16px;">
        <span>1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span>
</div>

<div style="padding:20px; border:1px solid black;">
        <span>1</span>
        <span>2</span>
        <span>3</span>
</div>
```

[image]

Se escrever o span lado a lado ele não coloca um espaço entre as palavras. Como eu faço para a segunda div que tem os spans quebrados ter o mesmo resultado que o primeiro?

Comment: Possível duplicata: [Por que as quebras de linhas entre elementos causam espaço entre eles?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/276760/99718)

Comment: Entendi como funciona esse espaçamento. Agora não consegui achar como eu consigo resolver isso.

Comment: @HeberLeonard, eu ia responder aqui, mas como é duplicada mesmo (não tinha reparado os comentários), coloquei uma [outra resposta lá](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/482834/69296). :)

Comment: Olá Heber, pode se resolver com `float` ou com `font-size:0` no elemento pai, veja detalhamente como fazer em: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/172077/3635 ou então usando comentários HTML `<!-- -->`, veja como fazer em: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/172266/3635